# Wrap long labels with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I would like to wrap my labels in ggplot2, but sadly I do not know where to put the code, I tried with scales and string library, but it doesn´t work, this is my code:

```
ES1_CHANGE <- ClimateFilter %>%
  select(lkredcc,
         lklmten,
         gvsrdcc,
         ownrdcc)

likert_howlikely <- ES1_CHANGE %>% gather(key = 'Question_num', value = 'Answer')

likert_howlikely$Answer <- factor(likert_howlikely$Answer,
                               levels=0:10,
                               labels=c('No at all likely', '1' , '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','9','Extremely likely'))



ggplot(data = subset(likert_howlikely, !is.na(Answer)), aes(x=Question_num)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Answer), position="fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette='PRGn', direction=-1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(0), labels=scales::percent_format()) +
  labs(title='How likely likert scale',
       x='Questions', y='Percent Answered') +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs('lkredcc' = "New x label") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('How likely, governments in enough countries take action to reduce  climate change ', 'How likely, large numbers of people limit energy use', 'Imagine large numbers of people limit energy use, how likely reduce climate change', 'How likely, limiting own energy use reduce climate change'))`
```

This is the plot tha I have until now:
[image: This is the plot tha I have until now]

Thanks

I tried different libraries, I watched some videos and read some blogs but nothing works so far, I would like that my plot looks better

Comment: Try inserting \n in the character strings. \n is the escape for the new line character.

Answer (score 1):

`stringr::str_wrap()` wraps strings to fit a certain width.

```r
stringr::str_wrap("Wrap me up!", 5)
#> [1] "Wrap\nme\nup!"
```

It inserts `\n` into the string after full words,
whenever the width value is reached. `\n` inserts a
newline whenever the string is printed in a plot.
We can use `cat()` the preview what that would look like:

```r
stringr::str_wrap("Wrap me up!", 5) |> 
  cat()
#> Wrap
#> me
#> up!
```

We can use `str_wrap()` within a `ggplot()` call.
First we create some data

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- 
  tribble(
  ~long_strings, ~value,
  "this is the first long string", 15,
  "here we have another long string", 33,
  "long words such as Sesquipedalianism can be a problem too", 32,
  "and finally this string is also pretty", 22
)
```

Here is a bar plot with no adjustments for the long axis tick mark labels.

```r
ggplot(df1) +
  geom_bar(aes(long_strings, value), stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

This what it looks like if we set the `width` to 15.

```r
ggplot(df1) +
  geom_bar(aes(str_wrap(long_strings, 15), value), stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

And a `width` of 10.

```r
ggplot(df1) +
  geom_bar(aes(str_wrap(long_strings, 10), value), stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]